SSRS IsNothing not working for null datetime
This is my expression but it is giving #ERROR for null DateExpired value
=SWITCH(
    IsNothing(Fields!DateExpired.Value), "N/A",
    Month(Fields!DateExpired.Value) = 2, "2/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Fields!DateExpired.Value)),
    Month(Fields!DateExpired.Value) = 6, "6/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Fields!DateExpired.Value)),
    Month(Fields!DateExpired.Value) = 8, "8/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Fields!DateExpired.Value)),
    Month(Fields!DateExpired.Value) = 10, "10/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Fields!DateExpired.Value)),
    Month(Fields!DateExpired.Value) = 12, "12/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Fields!DateExpired.Value)),
    Fields!DateExpired.Value
)


Just thought I'd put some ideas out there. This is usually a type error.
Please can you try:

adding a 'true' condition in the switch
converting the default condition to string

Something like this:
=SWITCH(
    IsNothing(Fields!DateExpired.Value), "N/A",
    Month(Fields!DateExpired.Value) = 2, "2/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Fields!DateExpired.Value)),
    Month(Fields!DateExpired.Value) = 6, "6/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Fields!DateExpired.Value)),
    Month(Fields!DateExpired.Value) = 8, "8/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Fields!DateExpired.Value)),
    Month(Fields!DateExpired.Value) = 10, "10/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Fields!DateExpired.Value)),
    Month(Fields!DateExpired.Value) = 12, "12/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Fields!DateExpired.Value)),
    True,
    Format(Fields!DateExpired.Value,"MM/d/yyyy")
)


The expression language for SSRS is Visual Basic.
IsNothing only works for reference types.  DateTime is a value type, so IsNothing will always return false.
The DateExpired value will either be some date, or it will be DbNull.Value.
DbNull.Value was introduced to represent nullable value types in .NET 1.0, and is still used in ADO.NET.

Ok, got it. But is there any way i can make it work? Like check for null value in DateTime

I tried IsDBNull but now the report is not opening in preview

There's no debugger, so you just have to simplify the expression to the point where it works, and build it back up from there.
